# 2D NSDictionary with NSArray

Tags: objective-c

The data set i'm trying to declare would look something like,

`$results[@"Key1"][@"Key2"] = @[int, int, int, int];`

How would one declare this combination of `NSDictionary` & `NSArray`?

Comment: `@{@"Key1": @{@"key2: @[@(int1),@(int2),@(int3),@(int4) ]}}`?

Answer (score 0):

So as far as I understand it, you're looking for an array within a nested dictionary - so an array, within a dictionary, within another dictionary.

I would declare it like this:

```
NSMutableDictionary *firstDictionary    =   [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
NSMutableDictionary *secondDictionary   =   [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
NSArray             *array              =   @[@1, @2, @3, @4];

[secondDictionary   setObject:array             forKey:@"key2"];
[firstDictionary    setObject:secondDictionary  forKey:@"key1"];
```

Then you can access the contents of your data structure like this:

```
NSArray *results = firstDictionary[@"key1"][@"key2"];

NSLog(@"results: %@", results);
```

And it will output:

```
results: (
    1,
    2,
    3,
    4
)
```

Hope this helps :)

*Edit: just as an aside, if you're trying to create a 2d matrix, where you use 2 coordinates to access your data, then you should probably use a nested array, instead of a nested dictionary.*